# Centos8 SVN1.10.2 can not ignore ssl validation

Tags: ssl, svn, centos8

A new CentOS Linux release 8.3.2011 system, install svn with 'sudo yum install subversion',the version of svn is 'svn, version 1.10.2 (r1835932)'

after execute command 'svn list https://mydomain:4443/svn/', I see blow chars:

svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://myserver:4443/svn/'
svn: E120171: Error running context: An error occurred during SSL communication

In centos 7, svn version 1.7. I will get a question and I can input 'p' to ignore ssl validation forever. But centos8 is not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with SVN, but with the SSL/TLS library packaged with the client and the SSL/TLS protocol it supports. I guess that that the newer svn client version does not support outdated SSL/TLS protocol versions for security reasons. You can always check the versions with the `svn --version -v` command.

Check which SSL/TLS versions your client and server support and consider upgrading the server. I think that it does not support modern SSL/TLS protocol versions.